# Grep list (file) from another file

Tags: bash, grep

Im new to bash and trying to extract a list of patterns from file:

File1.txt

```
ABC
BDF
GHJ
```

base.csv (tried comma separated and tab delimited)

```
line 1,,,,"hfhf,ferf,ju,ABC"
line 2 ,,,,,"ewy,trggt,gtg,ABC,RFR"
line 3 .."himk,n,hn.ujj., BDF"
```

etc

Suggested output is smth like

```
ABC
line 1..
line 2..(whole lines)
BDF
line 3..
```

and so on for each pattern from file 1

the code i tried was:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt -# cycle through all files containing pattern lists
do
for q in "$i"; # # cycle through list
do
echo $q >>output.${i}; 
grep -f "${q}" base.csv >>output.${i};
echo "\n";
done
done
```

But output is only filename and then some list of strings without pattern names, e.g.

```
File1.txt
line 1...
line 2... 
line 3..
```

so i don`t know to what pattern belongs each string and have to check and assign manually. Can you please point out my errors? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can process multiple files in one go, and then has the attractive added bonus of indicating which file it found a match in.

```
grep -f File1.txt base.csv >output.txt
```

It's not clear what you hope for the inner loop to do; it will just loop over a single token at a time, so it's not really a loop at all.

If you want the output to be grouped per pattern, here's a `for` loop which looks for one pattern at a time:

```
while read -r pat; do
    echo "$pat"
    grep "$pat" *.txt
done <File1.txt >output.txt
```

But the most efficient way to tackle this is to write a simple Awk script which processes all the input files at once, and groups the matches before printing them.

An additional concern is anchoring. `grep "ABC"` will find a match in `123DEABCXYZ`; is this something you want to avoid?  You can improve the regex, or, again, turn to Awk which gives you more control over where exactly to look for a match in a structured line.

```
awk '# Read patterns into memory
    NR==FNR { a[++i] = $1; next }
    # Loop across patterns
    { for(j=1; j<=i; ++j)
        if($0 ~ a[j]) {
            print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0 >>output.a[j]
            next }
    }' File1.txt base.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually reading the files, you're just handling the filenames. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt # cycle through all files containing pattern lists
do
  while read -r q # read file line by line
  do
    echo "$q" >>"output.${i}" 
    grep -f "${q}" base.csv >>"output.${i}"
    echo "\n"
  done < "${i}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that separates (with `split`, comma-separatd with quotes and spaces stripped off)  words from `file2` to an array (`word[]`) and stores the record names (`line 1` etc.) to it comma-separated:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    n=split($0,tmp,/[" ]*(,|$)[" ]*/)                                  # split words
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)                                                  # after first
        if(tmp[i]!="")                                                 # non-empties
            word[tmp[i]]=word[tmp[i]] (word[tmp[i]]==""?"":",") tmp[1] # hash rownames
    record[tmp[1]]=$0                                                  # store records
    next
}
($1 in word) {                                                         # word found
    n=split(word[$1],tmp,",")                                          # get record names
    print $1 ":"                                                       # output word
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                                                  # and records
        print record[tmp[i]]
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
ABC:
line 1,,,,"hfhf,ferf,ju,ABC"
line 2 ,,,,,"ewy,trggt,gtg,ABC,RFR"
BDF:
line 3 .."himk,n,hn.ujj., BDF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind help, my friends.
Tried both variants above but kept getting various errors ( "do" expected) or misbehavior ( gets names of pattern blocks, eg ABC, BDF, but no lines.
Gave up for a while and then eventually tried another way
While base goal were to cycle through pattern list files, search for patterns in huge file and write out specific columns from lines found - i simply wrote

```
for *i in *txt  # cycle throughfiles w/ patterns
do
  grep -F -f "$i" bigfile.csv >> ${i}.out1   #greps all patterns from current file
  cut -f 2,3,4,7 ${i}.out1>> ${i}.out2   # cuts columns of interest and writes them out to another file
done
```

I'm aware that this code should be improved using some fancy pipeline features, but it works perfectly as is, hope it`ll help somebody in similar situation. You can easily add some echoes to write out pattern list names as i initially requested